# Events are not Visible on UIImageView

Tags: iphone

I have a UIImageView, and a referencing outlet. However, altough I've set User Interaction of the ImageView, I cannot see any event in IB. Is it normal or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView is not a kind of UIControl, so you cannot set events to it. You have to use a UIButton with background, or subclass UIImageView and override the `-touchesBegan:` methods.